# Как правильно подключать svg4everybody?

Tags: svg, svg-спрайт

Скачал [библиотеку svg4everybody](https://github.com/jonathantneal/svg4everybody) судя по документации, нужно просто добавить такие строки:

```
<script src="Тут мой путь"></script>
<script>svg4everybody(); // run it now or whenever you are ready</script>
```

Что я и сделал, но никакого результата в `IE 11` я не заметил, то есть `SVG` иконки со спрайта не отобразились.

Иконки подключались подобным образом везде:

```
<svg>
    <use xlink:href='img/sprite.svg#comments' />
</svg>
```

Во всех остальных браузерах - работает, кроме `IE 11`.

Comment: а спрайт `sprite.svg` не забыли добавить в html с помощью <object>?  Только после добавления спрайта иконки из спрайта вызываются  `<use xlink:href='img/sprite.svg#comments' />`

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, нет, я не добавлял спрайт с помощью object, спрайт просто лежит в папке с картинками, но иконки и так вызываются в chrome, firefox, opera с помощью use

Comment: локально такой способ. как у вас будет работать, но после загрузки вашего приложения на сервер такой способ работает?

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, да https://uzinouzi.github.io/testtemplate/